# NodeJS losing socket connections then reconnecting

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have an application made in NodeJS+AngularJS, the user comes on the page and watches a video. I also have my moderator panel, where I can see how many users are on that page.
My problem is, if I have let`s say 200 users, 10 users or more are always droping then reconnecting all the time.
I have spent some time on debugging the socket.io, and this is what I got on the show page:

```
Manager {nsps: Object, subs: Array[4], opts: Object, _reconnection: true, _reconnectionAttempts: Infinity…}
_callbacks: Object
_reconnection : true
_reconnectionAttempts : Infinity
_reconnectionDelay : 1000
_reconnectionDelayMax : 5000
_timeout : 20000
attempts : 0
autoConnect : true
connected : 1
```

So my question is, can I change those values somehow ? I don`t want the users dropping and reconnecting all the time...

Many thanks!